# List Being Ordered Alphabetically Instead of Numerically

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have accumulated a list of scores with the username of the person who achieved that particular score in a list.

I then used the following code to order the scores in descending order.

```
winnerScore.sort()
winnerScore.reverse()
```

The following is the result when the list 'winnerScore' is printed.

```
['j 78', 'j 36', 'i 90', 'i 58']
```

The function has ordered them according to the username, instead of the actual code.

The function responsible for sorting the list is as follows:

```
global winnerScore
with open("diceRoll.txt","r") as x_file:
    contents = x_file.readlines()

oneScore = contents[count-1]
oneScore = oneScore.split(" ")
print(oneScore)
n = oneScore[-2][-1] + " " + oneScore[-1]

winnerScore.append(n)

if len(oneScore) != 0:
    winnerScore.sort()
    winnerScore.reverse()
```

I have read the scores and the username from a text file.

What can I change to make sure that the list 'winnerScore' is ordered based on the actual score of the usernames?

Answer (score 1):

To sort by number, you need to extract the number and treat it like an `int`, using it as the sort key. Like this:

```
winnerScore = sorted(winnerScore, reverse=True, key=lambda x: int(x.split()[1]))
```

The above expression will result in the value that you expected:

```
winnerScore
=> ['i 90', 'j 78', 'i 58', 'j 36']
```

Comment: I added that in and these were the results: ['h 52', 'z 52', 'z 82', 'h 68']

Comment: For me the result is `['z 82', 'h 68', 'h 52', 'z 52']`. I hope you didn't forget to assign the variable again ;) check my updated answer.

Comment: As soon as I posted that comment, I realised the mistake. But now it works :) thanks for your help!

Comment: @M.IbtihazIslam fantastic! please don't forget to accept the best answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the sort order for strings is alphabetical.

To customize the sort, you can add a [key-function](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-key-function).

Here's a worked-out example:

```
>>> def extract_number(score):
        "Convert the string 'j 78' to the number 78"
        level, value = score.split()
        return int(value)

>>> scores = ['j 78', 'j 36', 'i 90', 'i 58']
>>> scores.sort(key=extract_number)
>>> scores
['j 36', 'i 58', 'j 78', 'i 90']
```

Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that, that orders the elements of your input according by score

```
x.sort(key= lambda i:i.split(' ')[-1], reverse=True)
```

where x is the list containing the inputs, and the name and the score are separated by a whitespace (' ')

hope it helps xx

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expression in your custom `sort` function, this may help in case you have more than 1 space in your string:

```
import re
scores = ['j 78', 'j 36', 'i 90', 'i 58']

def get_score(username_score):
    score = re.search(r'\d+', username_score).group()
    return int(score)

scores.sort(key=get_score)
```

output:

```
['j 36', 'i 58', 'j 78', 'i 90']
```